# Defining nodes between two figures

Tags: tikz-arrows

I want an arrow between the two figures, I know I can do it using Tikz, but how can I define the coordinates of the middle points between the figures.

```
  \documentclass{beamer}
   \usepackage{tikz}
 \begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Advantages Vs. a Word processor}
 \underline{How dose it look like?} \\ \vspace{1em}

            \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
            \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
            {\tikz\node[coordinate](start1){};}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{Lat001.png}
            
            
\end{column}
  
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
{\tikz\node[coordinate](end1){};}
     \includegraphics[width=15cm,
  height=5cm,
  keepaspectratio]{Lat002.png}       
            \end{column}
            \end{columns}
            
           % \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, -latex, color=blue!15!red, 
% yshift=1ex, shorten >=1pt, shorten <=1pt, line width=0.1cm]
  % \path[->] (start1) edge [out=150, in=240] (end1);
%\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: ??????? your code does not compile

Comment: You need figures to compile it, should I upload them

Comment: The problem with your MWE is not so much the missing images but the two `\documentclass` commands,

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it depends what you want to put on this slide but I would not use a `columns` environment for the images. Instead, I would put both images inside a single `tizpicture` environment. Doing this way it is easy to draw the an arrow between them:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (start1) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=0.17]{example-image-a}};
  \node (end1) at   (10,0) {
    \includegraphics[width=15cm, height=5cm, 
        keepaspectratio=0.17]{example-image-b}
  };
  \draw[thick, ->](start1.east)--(end1.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you really need to put the images inside a `columns` environment then you can use [TikZmark](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/TikZmark):

```
\begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
  \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
     \tikzmarknode{start2}{
       \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{example-image-a}
     }
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
    \tikzmarknode{end2}{
      \includegraphics[width=15cm, height=5cm, 
          keepaspectratio=0.17]{example-image-b}
    }
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
       \draw[thick, ->](start2.east)--(end2.west);
    }
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

These two approaches lead to the following:

[image]

Of course, you will need to fine-tune the image placement and size using your real images. Here I have used example images from the [mwe](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}{Advantages Vs. a Word processor}
    \underline{How does it look like?} \\ \vspace{1em}

   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \node (start1) at (0,0) {
       \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{example-image-a}
     };
     \node (end1) at   (10,0) {
        \includegraphics[width=15cm, height=5cm, 
            keepaspectratio=0.17]{example-image-b}
     };
     \draw[thick, ->](start1.east)--(end1.west);
   \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{frame}

  \begin{frame}[fragile]{Advantages Vs. a Word processor}
    \underline{How does it look like?} \\ \vspace{1em}

    \begin{columns}[T,onlytextwidth]
      \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
         \tikzmarknode{start2}{
            \includegraphics[scale=0.17]{example-image-a}
         }
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.4\textwidth}
        \tikzmarknode{end2}{
          \includegraphics[width=15cm, height=5cm,
                  keepaspectratio=0.17]{example-image-b}
        }
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{ 
           \draw[thick, ->](start2.east)--(end2.west); 
        }
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}

  \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```